# how to use javascript into payload Karate framework REST request?

Tags: karate

I use Karate Framework (https://github.com/karatelabs/karate)

If I user this payload, my test is OK:

```
* def arrival = "22/10/2022"
* def duration = "10"
* def payload =
  """
  {
          "bb:foo": {
                "@Start": "#(arrival)",
                "@Duration": "#(duration)"
          }
  }
  """
```

If I use this payload, my test is KO:

```
@-foo
Feature: Foo

  Background:
  * def generatePayload = read('../../generatePayload.js')
  * def payloadRS = generatePayload(1)    
    
  @-barr
  Scenario: barr
        
    * print('payloadRS : ' + payloadRS)
    * def payload =
      """
      "#(payloadRS)"
      """

    Given url endpoint_ws
    And path '/rest/services/myservice'
    And request payload
    And header Content-Type = "application/json"
    When method post
    Then status 200
```

I try with javascript retun string, I try with javascript retun javascript object format.

how to with `def payload = ....` please?  I need all `#(varialbles)` are interpreter.

**EDIT:**

I find a start of solution but I looking for a solution for escape a '/' char

```
function generatePayload(num) {
    return {
              "bb:foo": {
                    "@Start": karate.get('arrival'),
                    "@Duration": karate.get('duration')
              }
      }
}
```

**Error:** My body contains `{"@Start":"12\/10\/2022"` instand of `{"@Start":"12/10/2022"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a JS function. For example:

```
Feature:

Background:
* def payload = 
"""
function(var1, var2) {
    return {
        first: var1,
        second: var2
    };
}
"""    

Scenario:
* def body = payload('foo', 'bar')
* match body == { first: 'foo', second: 'bar' }
```

Refer the docs: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#calling-javascript-functions

Comment: how to use global variable instand of variable in parameter please? in your case, for exemple `first: #(var1)`

Comment: @StéphaneGRILLON global variables should "just work". but you can try using `karate.get('varname')` and get them. read this: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#http-header-manipulation